# html h tag with text value in to php

Tags: php, html

This not working out for me. Any tips or example to make it work? post args = array($tags) didnt get value correctly.

```
<h6>seal</h6>
<h6>mark</h6>
<?php
    $tags = "<script>document.write(h6);</script>"; 

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'Rune', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tag' => $tags,

);
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

Comment: You are literally setting the `$tags`-variable to the string `<script>document.write(h6);</script>`, so unless you have a tag called exactly that, it won't work. You can't execute JS in PHP. PHP get's executed on the server and then returns the result to the browser, which renders HTML and executes any JS.

Comment: Please be more specific of what you are trying to do, and in what way your code doesn't do what you expect. Are you tring to pass a value from javascript to php? if yes, this is not how you do it. Do you try to inject dynamic script as a tag? because this is also not how it works

Comment: where is `echo` or any output method?

Answer (score 0):

`$tags` is going to equal the string `<script>document.write(h6);</script>`. PHP isn't going to evaluate your JS.

The result you're seeing is correct under the circumstances. You need to change the way you're getting tags in order to pass them in to your `$args` array.

Without knowing more about the problem I can't suggest a better approach to take.